# quickly initialize resources swift

Tags: string, swift, for-loop, resources

So, I'm trying to initialize/use many resources (specifically audio clips) in Xcode. Currently, I am just listing out the name of each resource separately (i.e. I have a very long column of statements only varying in document names such as "audio1", "audio2", "audio3", ... etc.). Is there a way to quickly do this? I was thinking about using an array and a for loop, seeing that the only difference in the names of the resources is the "1", "2", "3", etc., but I don't know how to vary one part of a string (the title for each audio clip).

Comment: Could you show what code you have put together so far?

Comment: So if you did initialize the files in threw the objects into an array you would just have the pointers to the objects in the array and any variable name you have assigned would be pointless. If you need to keep track of what the file are you could do something like `[String:AudioObject]` where the string is the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Array of Strings where each array element holds the corresponding filename with:

`let audioFile = Array(0...10).map { "audioFile\($0)" }`

Thus, `audioFile[1]` would be equal to `"audioFile1"`